# Creating a new directory in a Windows 10 Universal App UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am attempting to create a directory using this method that fires after a button press in app, as well as add a file to it:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"..\\newFolder\\");
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"..\\newFolder\\foo.txt");
if (!d.Exists)
{
    d.Create();
}
if (!f.Exists)
{
    f.Create().Dispose();
}
```

Here's the error that is producded in my Universal App as a result of doing this:

```
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' 
occurred in System.IO.FileSystem.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access to the path
 'C:\Users\[username]\Documents\MyApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\newFolder' is denied.
```

Any one familiar with this error or know of any suggestions?

EDIT
In addition to the below, this is a Great resource for working with file systems in the Windows 10 Universal App environment: File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758325.aspx

Comment: If you're using the `@"..."` syntax, you don't need to escape your backslashes. `@"..\newFolder\"` is sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every application runs under (by) a specific user and inherit it's privileges, authorities, limitations and ...
so
The User that your app runs under it, haven't enough privilege and can't create a folder
SO you can:

- Use **Impersonation** (search impersonation c#)  and code your app to runs as another User with required privilege (Like Administrator). after that your application always runs as administrator (or specific user) automatically. (If you impersonation your app as Administrator, Be aware of Security issues)
- Run your application as Administrator (or a user with enough privilege) manually. (for Administrator right click on your-app.exe and click on "Run as ...")
- Change security settings and access limits for your working directories (e.g C:\Users[username]\Documents\MyApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\newFolder ) and give **write access** to your username

Comment: your welcome :)
Please don't use comments for thanks.
If you find any answer useful (solved your problem) please mark it "accepted"

Comment: This is a Universal Windows app, and NT user permissions has nothing to do with it. This is failing because it's trying to write to its own installation folder, which is disallowed.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yes, I agree, It's is a Universal App and must be located and executed from a normal folder (with usual permission). In this Case his App run in above mentioned folder and it's folder located in "User" and "Documents" Directories . Usually personal directories like "Users" and "Documents" have limited permissions  (for security). So I suggest him to add write access to his working directory.

Comment: That won't help if the app is ever released in the store.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to create a file inside your app's install folder, and that is not allowed for Universal Apps. You can only create folders inside your local data folder.

Try this:

```
using Windows.Storage;

var localRoot = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(localRoot + "\\test");
if (!d.Exists)
  d.Create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public static async void  WriteTrace()
{
  StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
  StorageFolder LogFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("LogFiles", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your application with Administrative privileges and it should be done.

Comment: This is very rarely the best solution.

Comment: It also won't help in this case.